# Выход из режима EFI Shell для запуска windows

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, windows-10, shell

Есть планшет Onda на Androide, с Windows, не загружается Windows появляется efi shell version 2.31 и выйти из него не получается и загрузка Windows 10 не происходит, как выйти, нужен ли для этого загрузчик с Windows на флэшке?

Comment: Выпадаете в efi shell потому что нет загрузчика в разделе ефи. попробуй с установочной флешки загрузиться и выполнить восстановление запуска

Comment: Намекает как бы, что пора ставить Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Выпадаете в efi shell потому что нет загрузчика в разделе ефи. попробуй с установочной флешки загрузиться и выполнить восстановление запуска

[https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems#способ-1-средство-восстановления-запускаmethod-1-startup-repair-tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems#%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-1-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0method-1-startup-repair-tool)